# comparing lists for elements excluding one or more element python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hey :) How can I compare lists so that all elements of the lists match except for one element the color? If all other elements match, the lists should be concatenated into one.

```
fruitlist = [['Apple', 'red', 10], ['Apple', 'green', 10], ['Apple', 'pink', 10], ['Apple', 'yellow', 20], ['Banana', 'yellow', 10]]
```

output:

```
fruitlist = [['Apple', 'red, green, pink', 10], ['Apple', 'yellow', 20],['Banana', 'yellow', 10]]
```

***Is there also a solution here that applies to much longer lists? (excluding one or more elements)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an intermediate dictionary then construct your output list as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mdict = defaultdict(list)

fruitlist = [['Apple', 'red', 10], ['Apple', 'green', 10], ['Apple', 'pink', 10], ['Apple', 'yellow', 20], ['Banana', 'yellow', 10]]

for fruit, colour, n in fruitlist:
    mdict[fruit, n].append(colour)

print([[fruit, ', '.join(v), n] for (fruit, n), v in mdict.items()])
```

**Output:**

```
[['Apple', 'red, green, pink', 10], ['Apple', 'yellow', 20], ['Banana', 'yellow', 10]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. :)  But if the lists have e.g. 20 different elements, from which 2 are to be excluded, then it becomes probably a little confusing or?

Comment: @SameX Impossible to answer that without an example of the larger data. Maybe add that to your question